# Fade effect у swiper блокирует контент слайда

Tags: swiper

При использовании у swiper эффекта "fade", блокируется доступ к контенту внутри слайдов (ховер, клики и т.д). Если убрать этот эффект, контент внутри снова откликается на мышь.

Использую swiper веб-компоненты (не core, react, svelte, а element)
Когда кликаю правой кнопкой мыши, чтобы посмотреть, что под курсором, то показывает swiper-wrapper из теневого дом дерева.

Кто-нибудь знает как можно получить доступ к слайдам?